# issues linking pbc library into the C program in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

PBC library is installed in my system and I want to use it in my C program in Eclipse. So, I passed the include path and library path of PBC to the compiler. Later, when I try to build the program it gives the following error:

cc1: fatal error: /usr/local/include/pbc: No such file or directory

Comment: If the file is not in `/usr/local/include/pbc` path then it should be **Compilation error** and **not Linking error**. Can You share the Error which is displayed on console may be.

Comment: make all 
Building file: ../first.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I/usr/local/include/pbc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -include/usr/local/include/pbc -include/usr/include/glib-2.0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"first.d" -MT"first.o" -o "first.o" "../first.c"
cc1: fatal error: /usr/local/include/pbc: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'first.o' failed
make: *** [first.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Comment: Please add this text (above comment) in the Post. And paste it in code section of block quote.

Comment: And Yes this is a Compilation Error. It says you dont have `/usr/local/include/pbc` directory. Do You?

Comment: Note that the problem probably comes from `-include/usr/local/include/pbc`. That's wrong, the `-include` option is to include a header *file* (it's equivalent to putting `#include "/usr/local/include/pbc"` at the top of your source file). You should not need the two `-include` options at all.

Comment: @RC0993 yes, that is a compilation error, thanks for mentioning it, and I do have /usr/local/include/pbc directory.

Comment: Include the path which contains the `*.h` file `#include`d in the `*.c` file

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right, there should not be two -include options. While including the path of pbc, I was not mentioning the specific header file as well, which caused the compilation error. Thanks a lot!